# Should these questions be considered duplicates?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

[A user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5274/jonathan-allen) has [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414106/what-browser-specific-features-does-firefox-offer-for-web-developers) [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414114/what-browser-specific-features-does-chrome-offer-for-web-developers) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414555/what-browser-specific-features-does-safari-offer-for-web-developers) over the course of ~90 minutes, with nearly identical titles:

> What browser specific features does [Firefox|Chrome|Safari] offer for web developers?

and text:

> What browser specific features does [Firefox|Chrome|Safari] offer for web developers? By this I mean features that can be accessed via HTML/JavaScript but are not part of standards such as HTML 5.

Content aside, it seems like these should just be a single question rather than a different one for each browser. Thoughts?

Comment: I think these should be close as "not a real quesions" as they are far to open ended to be useful

Comment: That's what I'm thinking as well. I tried to ask the OP more about the sort of thing they were looking for - no luck yet, though.

Comment: Voting to close as not a real question with a vengeance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dunno.  Not answerable, but an interesting question relevant to developers.  Wiki'd. At this point, I'd let the community punish as desired.

Comment: Community punishment, activate!

Answer (score -3):

Most questions on Stack Overflow are duplicates.  People have settled on answering duplicates if they're interesting, and ignoring duplicates if they're not.

Looking at the three questions you list, I'm guessing they fall in the "uninteresting duplicates" bucket.  Nobody felt like spending time to close them.

Most likely the lack of answers will make clear to the user that his questions aren't good. If he continues to post triplicate duplicates, annoying many users, consider flagging his posts for moderator attention.